# SSL on single EC2 Linux instance running PHP: "connection refused" error

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to enable SSL on a single EC2 Linux instance running PHP but I get a "connection refused" error.

I followed these instructions to enable SSL: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html

And in step 4, I completed the steps to create a .config file (I made sure indentation was correct) and place it inside the .ebextensions folder: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ssl-singleinstance-php.html

Also, I created a new Security Group for HTTPS (Inbound HTTPS | TCP | 443 | 0.0.0.0/0).

After committing the change, I went ahead and deployed using aws.push. The deployment was successful (no errors). However, I see a "refused connection" error when trying to load my instance both on http and https.

In order to see if I could revert this situation, I removed the .config file and redeployed, but I still see the error, the site is not accessible at the moment.

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong? I read the answers that were given in similar questions, but I can't find a solution to this issue. I'm also wondering how I can revert the configuration to bring the site back.

Here's my config file:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
        SSLSessionTickets     Off

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early

        LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
        TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
      </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      mycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificateheremycertificate
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      myrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsaprivatekeyheremyrsapr
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since it might help others:

The issue was with the version of the Amazon Linux server (2014 instead of 2015). The config file above does not work with 2014 servers.